# How to execute Tasks in C#

Tags: c#

I don't understand why I can't see anything in the console by using the code below.

```
Task t = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
            });
```

But when I add `Console.WriteLine("Test");` at the end of the code it works. :

```
Task t = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                });
Console.WriteLine("Test");
```

I can't see the reason why the task won't run till it find a code after . I hope that my question is clear

Comment: I don't see whole code but try to wait for a Task - like  t.Wait();

Answer (score 3):

You should declare the `Main` method as `async` and `await` your task.

Like this:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Task t = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
        }
    });
    await t;
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Main() cannot be async in a console application (prior to C# 7.1). Use t.GetAwaiter(false).Wait() for earlier versions. (Edited because I haven't been using 7.1)

Comment: Please add something about why OP should use `async`/`await` instead of something else.

Answer (score 2):

You are not waiting for the `Task` completion and the app probably ends its execution before the `Task` starts.

```csharp
Task t = Task.Run(() =>
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }
});
Console.WriteLine("Test1");
t.Wait();
Console.WriteLine("Test2");
Console.ReadKey();
```

But your example doesn't show the real concurrent work.

Test this:

```csharp
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
        Thread.Sleep(5);
    }
}));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        Console.Write("!");
        Thread.Sleep(5);
    }
}));
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
{
    Console.Write("+");
    Thread.Sleep(5);
}
Console.WriteLine("Test1");
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine("Test2");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: so Run doesn't mean that the task is going to start ?

Comment: @user1187282 The task starts but your app doesn't wait for it and exists.

Comment: if it starts i should be able to see "*" in the console , right ? but it's not the case

Comment: @user1187282 starting new Task is ~30ms of processor time. If your program ends earlier, the Task will be interrupted before you see the stars.

Comment: @user1187282 just add simple `Console.Readkey()`

Comment: @user1187282 added one more example to the answer that will show what really happens.

Answer (score 1):

Simply wait for your task finish:

```
        Task t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
        });
        t.Wait();
```